# SimpleDateFormat question for timezone offset +AA:BB

Tags: java

I am currently using the following SimpleDateFormat pattern:
`String  DATE_TIME_FORMAT_PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss,SSSXXX";`

This works fine, however some raspberry Pi java implementations don't recognize it properly:

`timestamp                                 2020-01-21T09:41:45,434Z`

In most cases, this won't be an issue, however the offset is buggy for some raspberry PIs; I don't want that. Is there an alternative pattern with the same offset format (+/-HH:mm) that could work? I've tried all kinds of patterns, but none seem to produce the same output.

I also used the following tool to search for such a pattern: https://javadevtools.com/simpledateformat , though it was fruitless.

NOTE: An example output of this format is `1997-07-16T19:20:30,45+01:00` , with a colon in the offset.

Comment: What do you mean by "don't recognize it properly"? Please provide a [mcve] - at the moment it's hard to understand what you're asking.

Comment: Well, parsing a Date by this format yields results that have all information correct, with the exception of the offset. It ends up as 'Z'. I was wondering if there was a way to bypass this.
I'll try to set up an example to demonstrate this.

Comment: That `Z` means UTC time and is equivalent to an offset of `+00:00`. Is the hour adjusted correctly or is the offset adjusted (by system time of the Raspberry Pi, maybe)?

Comment: I think that the PI doesn't display the offset at all; it always ends up as Z. I'll do some research.

Comment: @VelitchkoValkov: A `Date` value doesn't *have* an offset. It's just an instant in time. See https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/ - but you'd be better off using java.time.

Comment: Note that `Z` is a perfectly valid ISO-8601 time zone offset value, equivalent to UTC. So it's not that it "doesn't display the offset" - it displays an offset of 0, as "Z".

Comment: That could explain things. I'll read the date page,thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirm that this is not a Pi issue. I switched my local time zone to UTC and ran the following example:

```
long current = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss,SSSXXX"); 
Date date = new Date(current);
String parsed = format.format(date);
System.out.println(parsed);
```

```
2020-08-31T15:05:27,872Z
```

And the Z appeared, on Windows 10. I have missed that part of the ISO spec. It seems I have to workaround my tests for this situation :). Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

If you were using [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html), especially the two classes [`java.time.OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) (pattern symbols are explained in this JavaDoc) and [`java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), you or your Raspberry Pi would be able to correctly parse the timestamp (which has a strange format using a comma to separate fractions of second from the seconds).

The following example parses your `timestamp` and outputs the default format:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String timestamp = "1997-07-16T19:20:30,45+01:00";
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[,SSS]xxx");
    OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(timestamp, dtf);
    System.out.println(odt);
}
```

Output:

```
1997-07-16T19:20:30.450+01:00
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! However, those 'xxx' characters don't get recognized if I use SimpleDateFormat. Do I have to use java.time and the corresponding formats in order to parse with this pattern?

I was wondering if there is a SimpleDateFormat that could work in this situation, so minimal interference in the old code would be possible :)

Comment: @VelitchkoValkov: You'd really be much better off purging `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date` and `Calendar` from everywhere in your code. The `java.time` API is *much* better, and will avoid misunderstandings like this one.

Comment: @VelitchkoValkov you're welcome, I don't know if a `SimpleDateFormat` can handle it, but it should be... However, it is strictly recommended to switch to the modern an less troublesome datetime API `java.time`.

Comment: Okay, I'll have to consider switching.
I'll leave the issue open for now , if anyone gets any ideas about this, and I'll create a proven test example as well.